# Store ConnectionStrings outside of MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am developing an MVC5 application and it is a requirements that all environmental configuration be stored outside of the application to enable simple deployment between environments. i.e. When a change is made, copy a bunch of files and don't worry about overwriting the web.config.

I have moved all the configurable settings to a SQL table which works fine, however, I am struggling to move the Connectionstrings outside of the web.config.

I am using EntityFramework within a C# MVC application. I am also using ELMAH for error handling.

I have tried executing the following from the Global.asax, but EntityFramework complains the connection string is not in the file:

```
private static void SetConnectionString(string connectionStringName, string connectionString)
    {
        var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
        var element = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var collection = typeof(ConfigurationElementCollection).GetField("bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        element.SetValue(settings, false);
        collection.SetValue(settings, false);

        settings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(connectionStringName, connectionString));

        collection.SetValue(settings, true);
        element.SetValue(settings, true);
    }
```

Is it possible to override the configurationmanager that Entity framework uses?

Edit: Solution.

So the solution was actually pretty simple. As i was using Code First EF I can actually pass in the connection string into the constructor:

```
public AdventureWorksDb(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
```

So, with the combination of the two, loading the connectionstrings from XML and modifying the ConnectionStrings Collection at runtime and then passing the correct connection string into the DBContext constructor I have a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

As Ewan mentioned, you can use the machine.config file for this purpose. You can also use the root web.config file. Both of these files are located in the `%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\[FrameworkVersion]\Config\` directory.

The application web.config file will override any settings in the machine-level files. So, the solution is to exclude your connection strings from the application web.config file that you deploy in order for the application to pick them up from the machine-level file.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that so good idea. The one thing I had failed to mention though as I didn't think it was relevant (I now stand corrected) is that I have multiple apps running with different SQL permissions all using the same database. I have figured out a solution and will add it to my question.